can i change an acer aspire 3 a315-41-r8th broken screen with a higher resolution one?
i have an acer aspire 3 with a broken screen wich was a 1366x768.
i would like to use a 1920x1080 screen to replace the broken one, would i be able to?
searching for my laptop's model number onlaptopscreen.com(i will be not using this site beacause i live in europe) the 1366x768 screen and the 1920x1080 one seem to have the same connector  and the screen i disassembled from my laptop seems to be the same one same one as well.
photos of stikers if needed:
sticker on the bottom of laptop
sticker on the back of the dissasembled screen

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You might try https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, instead, if you do not get an answer here.

to answer my own question:
i bought a 1920x1080 replacement screen (ean: 8053836254903) for the acer aspire 3 a315-41 SERIES and it worked without problems.
